# Out of memory on Image.FromFile

Tags: c#, image, file, windows-7, windows-10

I wrote on Windows 7 a program to read the QR code from an image dropped in a folder and worked fine, but now I'm trying it on Windows 10 and crashes.
I'm using Image.FromFile to read the file. It seems to work fine the first time, but the second time it throws a Out of memory exception.

Here is the code:

```
private void watcher_FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string strFileExt = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);

        if (Regex.IsMatch(strFileExt, @"\.jpg|\.png", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var b = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(e.FullPath))
                {
                    var result = reader.Decode(b);
                    if (result != null)
                    {

                        if (result.ResultPoints[0].X < result.ResultPoints[2].X)
                        {
                            if (result.ResultPoints[0].Y < result.ResultPoints[2].Y)
                            {
                                b.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (result.ResultPoints[0].Y < result.ResultPoints[2].Y)
                            {
                                b.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                b.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                            }
                        }
                        string fileName = result.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);
                        b.Save(Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["destinationFolder"], fileName));
                        client.SendData(result.Text + "|" + fileName, "qrListener");
                        Console.WriteLine("QR: " + result.Text + " File: " + fileName);
                    }
                }
                File.Delete(e.FullPath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I got to a point where I had removed everything inside the using and still crashed.

Comment: Do you try to write the bitmap to the same file you read it from? this should never have worked! use a stream!

Comment: When am I writing the image? You mean on the rotate or the save? Anyway, I removed all code inside the using and still threw the exception.

Comment: Hm, is it just one image or are there more? Can you tell us more about them?

Comment: here its one of the images. http://imgur.com/a/LCt0e. it happends with jpg and png.

Comment: Ok, the image is innocent. Here is what I suspect, but can't test for lack of time: The Filewatcher fires faster than once per second, so the filenames are not always different so the old problem of overwriting a file that is  in use comes up. could that be? Search for posts on overwriting files and you'll see many examples. One way is to do IO with streams..

Comment: Why you try Image.FormFile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the watcher triggered the first time when the file had already been unlocked, but the next times the file was still being written, incomplete, which makes the OOM exception to makes sense as

> If the file does not have a valid image format or if GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file, this method throws an OutOfMemoryException exception.

I added a method to check every 100ms if the file is unlocked.

Other thing I just noticed, it throw the exception when I copy the file and not when I move it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If the file does not have a valid image format or if GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file, this method throws an OutOfMemoryException exception.

I would think the image you are trying to load is not supported anymore. Can you upload an example picture to help us reproduce the image.

Maybe the internal structure of the image confuses the GDI+ encoders. Try to open the faulty image using an image editor and save it again. Now try to load the new image using your code.

Comment: Could you upload an image that causes the OOM exception for us to test.